How can I convert x and y coordinates in a NetCDF file to latitude and longitude for compatibility with Python's climate-indices library?
I am encountering a "ValueError: Invalid dimensions for variable 'pr': ('time', 'lat', 'lon')" when using my NetCDF with the climate-indices library.
I adjusted the NetCDF coordinates of my dataset (containing daily preciptiation data).
Initially, the dataset had 'lat','lon', 'x' and 'y' coordinates and 'time', 'x' and 'y' dimensions.
For compatibility with the climate-indices library, I need 'lat' and 'lon' dimensions. To achieve this, I used the xarray library in Python and tried the following:

Dropped the existing 'lat' and 'lon' coordinates from the dataset.
Renamed the 'x' and 'y' dimensions to 'lat' and 'lon', respectively.
Saved the updated dataset with the adjusted coordinates to a new NetCDF file.

However, whenever I run the command to compute the spi from the climate-indices package, I get "ValueError: Invalid dimensions for variable 'pr': ('time', 'lat', 'lon')".
Can someone tell me if the approach is wrong or what alternative steps I should take to make my netCDF work with the climate-indices package?
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# open and inspect dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset('kerpen_pr_hyras_1_1931_2020_v5-0_de.nc')
ds

# Drop 'lat' and 'lon' coordinates and rename dimensions to x and y
ds = ds.drop_vars(['lat', 'lon'])
ds = ds.rename({'y': 'lat', 'x': 'lon'})
ds.to_netcdf('kerpen_pr_hyras_1_1931_2020_v5-0_de_renamed.nc')
ds.close()

!process_climate_indices --index spi --periodicity daily \
--netcdf_precip C:\Users\skrautzi\Documents\jupyternotebooks\temperature_exercise_DWD    \air_temperature_mean_1951-2022_DWD\SPI3_kerpen\kerpen_pr_hyras_1_1931_2020_v5-0_de_renamed.nc \
--var_name_precip pr \
--output_file_base C:\Users\skrautzi\Documents\jupyternotebooks\temperature_exercise_DWD\air_temperature_mean_1951-2022_DWD\SPI3_kerpen\kerpen_pr_hyras_1_1960-2000-SPI3 \
--scales 90 \
--calibration_start_year 1960 \
--calibration_end_year 2000 \
--multiprocessing all


You will need to provide us with the raw data file. Potentially this is just a grid type that the package cannot handle, so you'll need to regrid. If you cannot post the data, add the grid type, which would point in the right direction

Thank you for your reply! The data is availble at: https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/hyras_de/precipitation/pr_hyras_1_1931_2020_v5-0_de.nc
or if the download takes to long, there is some single, here are the daily files with the same structure: https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/hyras_de/precipitation/

Don't drop the lot and lat variables from the dataset. They define 2D arrays of the actual longitude and latitude values. The values in the x and y arrays are not longitude and latitude values, but are apparently in terms of meters from some particular origin point, and have values on order of 10^6.

Ah, I should have looked a bit closer. The "cars_HYRAS" variable in your example datasets shows that the data are gridded on a lambert_conformal_conic grid, so the x and y vars are meters from the origin of that grid at 10°E 52°N after accounting for the specified false easting and northing values. So essentially, if you want a neat lon-lat grid of your data, you are going to have to re-grid from the coordinates in the dataset.

Thank you so much for that additional clarity! I think I was lacking the concept here and I get what went wrong here :)
